# Prolog: Related predicates with permuted arguments

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to declare the following in Prolog without being caught in an endless recursion?

```
left([X,Y], Z) :- left([Z,X], Y); left([Y,Z], X).
```

The semantics is that the list represents a vector given by two points and the second argument is a third point lying left of the vector.

A related question is, how one can declare the relation of "left" and "right" given by:

```
left([X,Y], Z) :- right([Y,X], Z).
```

without getting an endless recursion.

Comment: if it's a relation over numbers, why not directly compare numbers ?

Comment: your definition is endless-recursive in itself: it is still not defined what it means for a point to be "left" of a vector.

Comment: @Boris: I assume that there are facts given stating that, e.g. left([a,b], c). Then I would like to be able to infer that left([c,a], b) holds.

Comment: @CapelliC: left is not a relation over numbers but over constants like 'a', 'b', 'c' and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this directly in Prolog. You can express commutative relationships by introducing a predicate that enumerates the permutations for the fact, so for example:

```
left_of(A, B, C) :- left(A, B, C).
left_of(A, B, C) :- left(C, A, B).
left_of(A, B, C) :- left(B, C, A).

left(a, b, c).
```

Now the query should be

```
?- left_of(A, B, C).
```

Similarly, you should define `right_of` in terms of `left`.

Several things worth noting:

1. Keep the three arguments separate, as shown. It is good practice not to introduce unnecessary structures.
2. Prefer explicit clauses, instead of `;`. It makes your code far more obvious. The `;` is really easy to miss when reading the code; if you use it, put it at the beginning of the line, not in the middle somewhere or at the end
3. Prolog implementations that support tabling do not have this problem.

Comment: Oh, i should have thought of that. Thank you for that answer. The answer to the second answer follows directly from this.